# N-tier architecture, how to join my tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, n-tier-architecture

I'm new at n-tier architecture. I have 3 tables and i cannot join this tables with n-tier architecture and also repository pattern.

Database diagram:
[image: Database diagram]

Project Architecture:
[image: Project Architecture]

Project Architecture:
[image: Project Architecture]

Example Codes for entity Rooms (I'm doing same thing for all entities)

Repository

```
namespace Regency.Core.DataAccess
{
   public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T :class,IEntity,new ()
    {
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
        IQueryable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);



    }
}
```

EfRepositoryBase

```
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
         where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                var deletedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                deletedEntity.State = EntityState.Deleted;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                return context.Set<TEntity>();
            }
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                var updatedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                updatedEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Room Entity

```
    public class Rooms:IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        public string RoomHeadPicture { get; set; }
        public string RoomPicture { get; set; }
        public int RoomGuestSize { get; set; }
        public string RoomDescription { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }

    }
```

Dates Entity

```
   public class Dates:IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Availability { get; set; }
        public int RoomRateTypeId { get; set; }

    }
```

RoomRateType Entity

```
   public class RoomRateType:IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RateType { get; set; }
        public int Room_Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Room Dal

```
   public interface IRoomDal:IEntityRepository<Rooms>
    {
        //Custom Operations


    }
```

EfRoomDal

```
public class EfRoomDal:EfEntityRepositoryBase<Rooms,RegencyContext>,IRoomDal
{
}
```

RoomService

```
public interface IRoomService
{
    void Add(Rooms room);
    void Update(Rooms rooms);
    void Delete(int Id);
    Rooms GetById(int Id);
    IQueryable<Rooms> GetAll();

}
```

RoomManager

```
public class RoomManager : IRoomService
    {
        private IRoomDal _roomDal;
        public RoomManager(IRoomDal roomDal)
        {
            _roomDal = roomDal;
        }
        public void Add(Rooms room)
        {
            _roomDal.Add(room);
        }

        public void Delete(int Id)
        {
            _roomDal.Delete(new Rooms {Id = Id });
        }

        public IQueryable<Rooms> GetAll()
        {

            return _roomDal.GetList();
        }

        public Rooms GetById(int Id)
        {
            return _roomDal.Get(x => x.Id == Id);
        }



        public void Update(Rooms rooms)
        {
            _roomDal.Update(rooms);
        }


    }
```

Controller

```
 public class AdminController : Controller
    {

        private IDateService _dateService;
        private IRoomService _roomService;
        private IRoomRateTypeService _roomRateTypeService;


        public AdminController(IDateService dateService, IRoomService roomService, IRoomRateTypeService roomRateTypeService)
        {
            _dateService = dateService;
            _roomRateTypeService = roomRateTypeService;
            _roomService = roomService;


        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            _roomService.GetAll();

            return View();
        }




    }
```

My question: what is the best way for join this three tables with architecture ?
and how to get join data in controller.

Thanks for helps. Because i'm stuck about this.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images. Also consider cutting some of this out. It's a lot to take in and I question whether all of it is necessary in understanding the question (although it may be).

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Seems like you're making things hard for yourself.  Just use EF and join as you need to.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Yes sir, I'm editing right now.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Because i want to learn n-tier architecture.

Comment: over engineered. You should learn the concepts Architecture and Design, what are logical and physical layers/tiers before trying to implement something like this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not implementing this correctly. Repositories are for working with aggregate roots. In DDD, subordinate relationships are never managed directly, but rather through the aggregate root. For something like your example, `Room` is your aggregate root, and thus what you would have a repository for, while `RoomRateType` and `Date` are subordinate entities that you'd manage via `Room`. For example, you might have methods on `Room` like `GetRoomRates` or `AddRoomRate`, which would use `RoomRepository` to fetch or modify that relationship on `Room`.

That said, if you're using Entity Framework, you shouldn't have any of this at all. The `DbContext` is your unit of work, and each `DbSet` is a repository. Opting to use an ORM like EF, is opting to use a third-party DAL. There's zero point in creating your own DAL over that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your source or angle is for learning n-tier architecture but I do agree that you can make it a bit easier for yourself and leverage the OOB EF functionality.

In terms of your question, all you need is to expose properties for the relationships in your models. For example:

```
public class RoomRateType
{
     public Rooms Room { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will automatically map this based off your database table foreign keys. If by any chance you need some custom mapping then you can map these using Entity Framework's Fluent API. Read [this post](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx) for more info.

HTH